# Constructing Key:Value pair from list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pytorch

I am trying to extend some code.

What works:

```
pretrained_dict = {k: v for k, v pretrained_dict.items if k in model_dict}
```

However, if I extend it to:

```
pretrained_dict = {k: v if k in model_dict else k1:v1 for k, v, k1, v1 in zip(pretrained_dict.items(), model_dict.items()) }
```

The code fails, If I put the else at the end it still fails:

```
 pretrained_dict = {k: v if k in model_dict for k, v, k1, v1 in zip(pretrained_dict.items(), model_dict.items()) else k1:v1}
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I construct the key value pair using an if else condition over two lists?

Comment: Looks like you want a dictionary that returns values from `pretrained_dict` and if the key doesn't exist than lookup the key in `model_dict`?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you shared some sample data and your desired outcome.

Comment: First snippet has a typo in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) to achieve what you want without having to use comprehensions at all

```
from collections import ChainMap
pretrained_dict = ChainMap(pretrained_dict, model_dict)
```

This returns a dictionary-like object that will lookup keys in `pretrained_dict` first and if it is not present then lookup the key in `model_dict`

Comment: thanks, but what is required is: lookup model_dict's keys in pretrained_dict and if found then update the key else keep the original key from model_dict

Comment: This will give you an object that will do just that

Comment: @IainShelvington. Sort of. It will also contain all the keys in `pretrained_dict` that aren't in `model_dict`, which OP doesn't want.

Comment: @tstseby. That requirement should be part of the question. And don't forget to mention which keys you're allowed to have in the resulting dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the second comprehension doesn't work is that the ternary operator only applies in the value. Luckily, both cases apply to the same key, so you can actually simplify the syntax a little. If that was not the case, you'd have to use two separate ternary operators or a `for` loop.

Another problem is that you don't show the grouping in your loop variables. `dict.items` yields tuples, and you have to make it clear how to unpack them.

So:

```
pretrained_dict = {k: v if k in model_dict else v1 for (k, v), (k1, v1) in zip(pretrained_dict.items(), model_dict.items())}
```

However, this won't actually do any of the lookup that you want. If your goal is to accept keys from `pretrained_dict` into `model_dict` in bulk, then you need to use `model_dict.update` with the appropriate keys. Zipping two dictionaries together is generally meaningless, since they won't have the same keys, and so it's unclear what the result would even be. Using a comprehension here isn't keeping with the literal requirement here either, since it necessarily means replacing rather than updating. In either case, your result should affect `model_dict`, not `pretrained_dict`.

Here is how you would do an update:

```
model_dict.update((k, v) for k, v in pretrained_dict.items() if k in model_dict)
```